# Is it possible to hack a computer if you download pdf file with executable content within the pdf?

Tags: file

I am worrying since I have been downloading some pdf files for my study. Our teacher a various pdf file lessons about computer and I am hesitant to download since there is a pop up alert saying there is executable code within the pdf file.

I hope you respect my problem and have a respectable answer. Thank you!

I am hoping you could help me.

Comment: Looks off topic here, maybe try https://security.stackexchange.com/